# PowerBI streaming dataset limitations

Tags: powerbi

We have a requirement of generating reports on PowerBI for real time transactions. We have roughly 2000,000 transactions flowing in 1 day and we would like reports generated atleast for these number of rows.
We have I understand that the push streaming API has a limitation of 200,000 rows for FIFO datasets and 5,000,000 for "none retention policy" [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/automation/api-rest-api-limitations)

My questions are as follows:

1. If we create a streaming data set push API via the PowerBI service, what dataset is created by default in the background? FIFO or the none retention policy dataset?
2. For a none-retention policy dataset, what happens when we cross the 5000,000 limit? If there is a failure, does that mean we need to delete old rows via an API call on a frequent basis? An example API to do this will help. Deleting all rows is not an option as business would like reports like KPIs over the last 24 hrs for example.
3. If we use Azure stream analytics to push data to PowerbI, what are the limitation of data storage in PowerBI in this case?

Comment: If you need to do this, use Streaming Analytics to a SQL database, or Azure Databricks streaming dataframes, to a datalake or other DB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you misunderstood the idea of Power BI. Power BI is not a database! Do not try to use it as such. There are better options out there. That's why you have hard times trying to work around these limitations.

What I'm trying to say is that you should store and process your data somewhere else. Use Power BI for visualizing it only. In this case, if we say that you want to use real-time streaming, which must be updated every second, this means you need to send only 86,400 records per day (which is way less than the limit of 200,000 records of a FIFO dataset). If you do not want to use real-time streaming dashboard, but a normal Power BI report, then why you are looking at push datasets? So collect your data somewhere, aggregate the results, and then push the aggregated data to Power BI.

And to answer your questions anyway:

1. If you create a dataset using the [Power BI REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_postdatasetingroup) without specifying the retention policy, it will create Push dataset with `none` retention policy - `basicFIFO` [must be enabled explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/automation/api-automatic-retention-policy-for-real-time-data).
2. If you reach the limit of 5M rows, you will get an error when trying to push more rows to the dataset. Your only option is to [delete all rows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/pushdatasets/datasets_deleterowsingroup) - there is no way to delete only some of them, because Power BI is not a database. That's why your data should be stored somewhere else and this is the idea behind `basicFIFO` retention policy and Power BI's [streaming dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-real-time-streaming#streaming-dataset).
3. Power BI limits doesn't change based on the data source. It doesn't matter are you pushing data through Azure Stream Analytics or a service written by you - the Power BI dataset is the same.

Comment: Thank you. Very useful information. We have decided not to go for streaming datasets. However we would still need direct query as we would like the point-in-time information for any report. Using import will require frequent refreshes. Thanks again.